# Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I have installed magento 1.9. I want to display all products in home page.

So i add the code in home page content section,

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

But it displays Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 74.

But when i add new products in home page it will work fine.

May i know how to fix this.?

Any help gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done any modifications to list.phtml?

Comment: @Shivanand, I checked the original code and found this error possible!
I have a fix for it, but I don't know if it's possible to edit magento packaged files

Comment: it is possible to edit the package files. But first you need to copy them to you own theme package if they are of theme package file or to code/local if they are of code/core files, with same directory structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple edit to the list.phtml file would fix this error

Here is the file location

```
Magento/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/
```

Change the snippet going from line 73 to 80, to :

```
<?php
$_nameAfter = $this->getChild('name.after');
if(is_object($_nameAfter)):
    $_nameAfterChildren = $_nameAfter->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')
                                ->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
        ?>
        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Please refer to these two wiki articles on how to customize a template :

- [Wiki 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/package)
- [Wiki 2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/how_to_customize_frontend_template_f.e._review.phtml_of_onepage_checkout)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
```

to

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers');
```

this will resolve your issue